# Can I transmit audio sampled with I2S driver from ESP32 using Si24R1 (Chinese clone of nRF24L01)?

Tags: spi, esp32, nrf24l01, i2s, digital-audio

I'm trying to transmit audio via nRF24 with an ESP32 development board using a driver [library](https://github.com/nopnop2002/esp-idf-mirf) from [nopnop2002](https://github.com/nopnop2002). I'm using the i2s-adc esp-idf lib functions to get data from an analog microphone and I need to get this I2S stream through the SPI interface between the ESP32 and the nRF24L01 breakout board clone. **Is this possible?**

I've seen some people mention on the internet that Nordic Semiconductors has nRF chips that support I2S but I would rather stick to the hardware I have available.

Here's the [link](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/30467/sending-i2s-signal-through-nrf24l01) I've consulted.

Thanks for the help in advance!